# Scala factory pattern improve design

Tags: scala, factory

I have written the following class and corresponding companion object:

```
class Tile(val tileCoordinate: Int, val pieceOnTile: Piece) {
    override def toString(): String = {
        if(isOccupied()) {
            pieceOnTile.toString()
        }
        "-"
    }

    def isOccupied(): Boolean = pieceOnTile != null
}

object Tile {
    def apply(coordinate: Int, piece: Piece): Tile = {
        new Tile(coordinate, piece)
    }

    def apply(coordinate: Int): Tile = {
        new Tile(coordinate, ??) // what is the best design here?An Option?
    }
}
```

My question is, when the factory method to create a `Tile` without a `piece` on it is invoked, what is the appropriate argument to pass in to the `Tile` constructor?  I don't want to pass in `null`, that seems like a poor design choice.  Should I have the main constructor take an `Option[Piece]` and pass in `None`?

That seems sort of ugly too because when I want to create a tile I'd need to say:

```
val t = Tile(1, Some(new Knight()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would ditch the `class` and `companion object` completely, and instead go for a `case class`:

```
case class Tile(tileCoordinate: Int, pieceOnTile: Option[Piece] = None) {
  override def toString(): String = pieceOnTile.map(_.toString).getOrElse("-")
}
```

This allows you to later do the following when checking for values:

```
... match {
  case Tile(c, Some(p)) => ...
  case Tile(c, None) => ...
}
```

Having the second parameter default to `None` allows you to call it as `Tile(coord)`, `Tile(coord, None)` and `Tile(coord, Some(piece))`

Comment: Case classes seem like the cleanest approach, thank you

Comment: can you have a case class and add an additional factory method to it?

Comment: @AmirAfghani, yes, you can. Just define a companion object for the class and add methods to it. These methods should not clash with compiler-generated methods, though.

Answer (score 3):

I would code the following:

```
class Tile(val tileCoordinate: Int, val pieceOnTile: Option[Piece]) {

  // A little bit more scala-idiomatic, and a probable bug corrected
  override def toString(): String = pieceOnTile.map(_.toString).getOrElse("-")

  def isOccupied : Boolean = pieceOnTile.isDefined

}

object Tile {

  def apply(coordinate: Int, piece: Piece): Tile = {
    new Tile(coordinate, Some(piece))
  }
  def apply(coordinate: Int): Tile = {
    new Tile(coordinate, None)
  }

}
```

Comment: The toString() method can also be written using pattern matching if you are not accustomed to using "map" in this way

Answer (score 2):

If `pieceOnTile` is optional, then you should use `Option` for sure. If you don't like the ugliness of having to wrap the `Piece`s in `Some` when creating new instances of `Tile`, then hide it within `apply`:

```
class Tile(val tileCoordinate: Int, val pieceOnTile: Option[Piece]) { ... }

object Tile {

  def apply(coordinate: Int, piece: Piece): Tile = new Tile(coordinate, Some(piece))

  def apply(coordinate: Int): Tile = new Tile(coordinate, None)
}
```

Then even `isOccupied` will look more scala-like:

```
 def isOccupied() : Boolean = pieceOnTile.isDefined
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  Definitely a usable approach

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative could be to define empty/occupied cases as separate case classes:

```
sealed abstract class Tile(val isOccupied: Boolean)

case object EmptyTile extends Tile(false) {
  override def toString: String = "-"
}

case class OccupiedTile(piece: Piece) extends Tile(true) {
  override def toString: String = piece.toString
}
```

You can use `EmptyTile`, create `OccupiedTile(piece)` and you can check a Tile either by the `isOccupied` flag or by pattern matching.

One possible advantage of this approach is that if you add more methods that assume a contained piece, you will not have to add checks of occupiedness to each method because you could define them only in `OccupiedTile` in the first place.